# JQuery DataTable does not allow using colspan (Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, html-table

I want to merge some columns in my html table with colspan but I use JQuery DataTable to export to Excel. I know that, I can not use colspan or rowspan in JQuery Datatable. Is there any solution? What should I do?

Comment: You'll need to re-work the table to not use col/rowspans. Depending on your useage, [child rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) might be interesting to you

Answer (score 1):

DataTables does not support `rowspan` or `colspan`.

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/89802/#Comment_89802